# tomcat context defined in server.xml is not loading

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu

I have a web application deployed on path

```
/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/abc/</code>
```

in `server.xml` on path `/etc/tomcat/server.xml` I have added following lines.

```
<Context docBase="/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/abc/" path="/" reloadable="true">

  <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="10000" name="jdbc/abcDB" password="abc" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/abc" username="abc"/>

</Context>
```

inside the host tag.

When I restart tomcat and hit `http://localhost:8080/` nothing appears but when I enter `http://localhost:8080/abc` home page is displayed which means above entry in `server.xml` is not taking affect.

What am I doing wrong ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you want to set webapp `abc` as the default web app (i.e. access it directly via http://localhost:8080/), then give the path as `""` not "/" in `Context`

From the Tomcat docs,

> If you specify a context path of an
>   empty string (""), you are defining
>   the default web application for this
>   Host, which will process all requests
>   not assigned to other Contexts