# Tomcat - making a project folder the web root

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I have this folder under Tomcat `webapps/mysite` which is where all my JSPs and other things are located. To access this folder I go to http://blah.com/mysite and it works just fine. However (because of stylesheets and images statically connected to the root `/`) I have to make it so that when I go to http://blah.com/ it will load the stuff inside `webapps/mysite`.

I've tried many different things including contexts and setting the absolute path in `server.xml`... nothing seems to work, whenever I go to http://blah.com/ it still tries to load the ROOT folder... what's happening here?

Comment: What do you mean when you say that the stylesheets and images are "statically connected to the root"?  Are they located in webapps/ROOT?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution I use is to set this in your Tomcat `server.xml`

Add a `<Context>` element within the `<Host>` like below which sets your `mysite` as the default web app. Note the empty `path=""` which makes it the default.

```
<Context docBase="mysite" path="" />
```

> Attributes of Context Container from the Tomcat docs:
>
> **docBase**    You may specify an absolute pathname for this directory or WAR file, or a pathname that is relative to the appBase directory
>   of the owning Host.
>
> **path**    All of the context paths within a particular Host must be unique. If you specify a context path of an empty string (""), you are
>   defining the default web application for this Host, which will process
>   all requests not assigned to other Contexts.

See others who have had similar question and the similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283227/tomcat-context-defined-in-server-xml-is-not-loading/3283409#3283409), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719387/tomcat-configuration-for-development-how-to-add-a-webapp-as-well-as-reference-s/3724794#3724794) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471656/virtual-host-or-proxy-to-a-webapplication-with-apache-2-2-and-tomcat-6/3474253#3474253)

See also [Apache Tomcat Configuration Reference - Context](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/context.html)

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways to make an application the root application.  The simplest way is to just replace the contents of webapps/ROOT with the contents of your web application.

For other solutions, please see the following website:
http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#How_do_I_make_my_web_application_be_the_Tomcat_default_application_.3F

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1123501/george-siggouroglou 's awnser works but lacks a step.

- delete ROOT and all items
- copy the war to webapps as ROOT.war

Without the deletion, it may not work. Tested with docker.

Answer (score 0):

You can rename your war from **something.war == to ==> ROOT.war**.
So, tomcat will unpack the war and will create the folder ROOT for it.
It is a trick that is working on tomcat 8 also.