# Tomcat WTP in eclipse: route all requests to same Servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, tomcat7

I am using Tomcat as WTP in eclipse, and I want to route all Incoming requests to my own Servlet.

When just mapping the Servlet to `"/"`, only requests like: `"http://localhost:8080/myServletName/anyUrlPattern"` are redirected,

but I want:
`"http://localhost:8080/anyUrlPattern"` redirect too.

Tomcat maps the default-servlet to `"/"` so I guess something has to be done there..

**As commented below, the solution is to set the Context in the server.xml**

Comment: Did you try to map your servlet to `/*`?

Comment: possible duplicate or at least related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044129/tomcat-making-a-project-folder-the-web-root and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437465/java-how-to-change-context-root-of-a-dynamic-web-project-in-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

As far as I recall that is not possible and/or discuraged, because the `<display-name>` is used to distinguish between (possibly) multiple WebApps running on your tomcat.