# Change default tomcat7 webpage to my app

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

How can I display my application as a default webpage? (currently there is default tomcat website)
Let say my domain is:

```
 http://mywebsite.com
```

When I type this in my browser I have tomcat default website with links to manager etc.
My application is avaiable from:

```
 http://mywebsite.com/coolapp
```

Is it possible to set my app to be displayed instead of that default tomcat website?

edit:
sorry forgot to mention it must be in folder coolapp so I cant deploy this as something else. Maybe it's possible to set that coolapp became root folder?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/4044129/289396

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found solution..

Edit server.xml file and add this line:

```
<Context path="" docBase="my/tomcat/path/webapps/coolapp" debug="0" reloadable="true"/>
```

After that restart Tomcat.

Comment: Well this works only on my Linux server. The same thing doesn't work on windows :(

Answer (score 0):

Remove ROOT folder and change your apps war name to root.war, restart Tomcat, rather than giving your app war the name coolapp.war in the webapps directory.

Comment: But it must be in folder coolapp because other things on the server using exactly this path and I can't change it. Is it possible to set somewhere ROOT folder path and point this on coolapp?